# Save edited data to mongodb database using reclinejs

Tags: javascript, django, mongodb

I had implemented the inline edit using the reclinejs in django and i am able to edit the data and update it,but when i refresh the page it revert back to old data, I tried many things but none worked.How can i save the edited data into the database.I am using mongodb as my database.

Below is the js(reclinejs) code by which i can edit the data.
(data_edit.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var dataset = new recline.Model.Dataset({
    formUrl: formJSONUrl,
    dataUrl: mongoAPIUrl,
    backend: "MongoAPI"
});

dataset.fetch().done(function(dataset) {
    var grid = new recline.View.Grid({
  model: dataset
});
$('#data-grid').append(grid.el);

dataset.fetch().done(function(dataset) {
  if (console) {
    console.log(dataset.records);
  }
});

$('#save-button').bind('click', function() {
              //alert($(this).text());
              dataset.save();
            });

        });

      })
~
```

This is the html file code responsible for view 
data_view.html

```
{% block content %}
    <section id="data-view">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>{%  trans "Data View" %} <small><a href="{% url main.views.show owner.username xform.id_string %}">{{ xform.title }}</a></small></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <span class="span12">
            <div id="data-grid"></div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </span>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="save-button">
          <form action="?" method="POST">
             {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="">
</form>
</section>
```

Comment: According to this page http://reclinejs.com/docs/tutorial-backends.html, recline.js does not support MongoDB as a backend. Did you write your own backend for Mongo, or are you sure that your Mongo backend is working correctly?

Comment: i found a open source api and i have rewritten it according to my needs it connects to mongodb that connects and fetches data from it....